# How safe is TOR for authentication based internet access?

Tags: windows-7, tor

My organisation required login before you can use internet. So, I have to login before I can use TOR.  Can the andministrator see my TOR traffic ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The administrator(s) can certainly see *that* you are connecting to a TOR network –– specifically, they will be able to see what TOR server you are connecting to, although that might be randomly determined and periodically, randomly changed –– and will be able to see how much traffic you’re sending and receiving (so they may be able to guess whether you’re uploading, downloading, or just browsing).  If they have found a security vulnerability in TOR and kept it a secret, then all bets are off; but that’s unlikely.  Otherwise, they won’t be able to see the content of your TOR activity simply from network monitoring.  But be aware: if you are using an organization-owned computer, they might have installed spyware on their machines.  If that’s the case, they can potentially see everything you see and everything you do.

Answer (score 2):

TOR encrypts your traffic between every nodes. Your network administrator will see encrypted traffic to a TOR node but he won't be able to see what this traffic contains.

Comment: Is there a way to know that traffic is encrypted. I mean it has not been compromised.

Comment: When you use TOR, your traffic is automatically encrypted. To check that you have correctly configured TOR, go to https://check.torproject.org

Comment: Your administrator WILL see encrypted traffic to an IP that is publicly known as a TOR node.